# Use JSON value in JS

Tags: javascript, html, json

I' currently having some problems with how I can get JSON values into a JS script. I would love to get some help with this! (I'm pretty new to these things)

This is the code I want the values to be in (lat and lon)

```
      var map;
  function initMap(lat) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: lat, lng: lon},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
```

The script I use:
https://pastebin(dot)com/6PKsW9G2

My HTML: 
https://pastebin(dot)com/aAfnevcp

Comment: did you mean how to import json data to js file, or you already have a json data format - you need to take values from that

Comment: I want to use the latitude and longitude values that I get via the JSON in my maps latitude and longitude values.

Comment: thats what I am asking, from where did you get your JSON ? did you make an file.json file and need to import to your js file. or you create a json object inside your js e. const json = [{'lat': 1, 'long': 2}]. or did you get the cordinates from a url response.

Comment: Post your code within your question. Not on an external site using broken links.

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet, u need to send parameter for lon as well.
You can access a json by its key.
Example : Json :var lat = { 
                  "key":"abcd"
}

you can access the value by lat['key'].
I hope tha tanswers your question of how to get a json value

Comment: Can you put it in a code (mine would be great haha) so I can see it in a context?